# Time between two timestamp (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, time, timestamp

Is there a way to have the time (HH:mm) between two timestamps in postgresql ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between two timestamps can be calculated using `-`, e.g.:

```
 timestamp_one - timestamp_two
```

However, the result is not a "time", but an "interval".

You can display that in the form HH:mm using to_char():

```
to_char(timestamp_one - timestamp_two, 'HH:mi')
```

but what do you expect for differences larger then 24 hours?